# Como mostrar el Total de tabla en grafico de columnas agrupadas

Tags: powerbi

Requiero mostrar el total que se encuentra al pie de una tabla de datos en un grafico de columnas agrupadas en Power BI, es decir, este total que se encuentra aquí en la parte inferior de la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deseo mostrarlo como valor en un grafico de columnas agrupadas junto al valor de 387 de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es importante dejar claro que la columna de donde se obtiene el valor `4:7 4:42 5:38` son columnas hechas a partir de una medida, es decir, se hizo uso de una formula DAX para su elaboración por esta razón no se me permite arrastrar la columna al apartado de Valores en el grafico de columna agrupadas, cada vez que lo intento ubicar en Valores se mueve automáticamente a Información sobre herramientas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columna `PromedioHoraPlanta` es la que corresponde a valor total mostrado de 4:7 en la tabla.

Quisiera que alguien me pueda dar una orientación en como poder colocar el total en la grafica de columna agrupadas

**Actualización:**

Explico un poco mas a detalle que es lo que utilizo para calcular la columna `PromedioHoraPlanta` que es la que corresponde a los valores de `7:28 5:56 5:21 8:55 9:49 3:45` se realizar a partir de una medida con la siguiente formular DAX:

```
= FORMAT(AVERAGE(Consulta1[t_TOTAL_SALIDA_seg])/3600 , "##") & ":" & FORMAT(MOD(AVERAGE(Consulta1[t_TOTAL_SALIDA_seg]),60), "##" )
```

El tipo de dato de la columna `t_TOTAL_SALIDA_seg` que es la que estoy usando para calcular la nueva medida en la formula DAX anterior es Número Entero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualización 2:**

Investigando un poco mas sobre este requerimiento al parecer no es posible hasta que convierta la duración en un valor numérico.

Ya que los datos de tiempo y duraciones son como fechas y texto, es por esta razón que solo puedo ponerlos en el eje x y no en los valores de la grafica de barras ya que se consideran datos categóricos ya sean en un gráfico de líneas, grafico de columnas o grafico de barras como en mi caso.

Además si observan en la primera captura de pantalla que agregue al comienzo de la pregunta, el valor `4:7` no es realmente el total de esa columna, esto se debe a la parte de los días que esta oculta por el formato.

**Actualización 3:**

Este requerimiento radica principalmente de un reporte que se encuentra realizado en SSRS en donde en su grafica de barras muestra el total que se representa en la tabla de la siguiente manera, dejo claro que las siguientes imágenes son del reporte pero realizado en SSRS.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es por esto que estoy intentado representar el mismo grafico de barras en Power BI, intentando mostrar el Total de la tabla como valores en la grafica de barras.

**Actualización 4:**

Después de un fin de semana de mucha investigación he decidido optar por la siguiente medida:

```
NuevaMedida = VAR _AVG = AVERAGE(Consulta1[t_TOTAL_SALIDA_seg]) VAR _LeftPart = DIVIDE(_AVG, 3600) VAR _RightPart = MOD(_AVG,60) RETURN _LeftPart * 100 + _RightPart
```

Intente optar por esta medida pero no consigo el resultado exacto, es cercano al total de cada columna pero no es el exacto al que se muestra en la tabla.

La siguiente imagen es del total que se muestra en el inferior de la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La siguiente imagen son los valores que se muestra en la grafica de barras:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven sus resultados son cercanos pero no son exactos, además de que aun no consigo que se separe con el carácter `:`, quisiera saber si hay algo que deba cambiar a la medida que he creado para que muestre su resultado exacto, creo que es lo mas cercano a lo que he estado de conseguirlo pero lastimosamente no es el resultado exacto.

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: lamentablemente no podemos reproducir tu pregunta para buscar o darte una respuesta. ya que tu ejemplo no es reproducible a menos que alguien aquí cuente con licencia y los datos necesarios...

Comment: ahora buscando un poco por internet encontré estas dos opciones: [Link-1](https://www.pbiusergroup.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=486310e3-bb0c-4871-8da9-c7d6fb0545ed&CommunityKey=b35c8468-2fd8-4e1a-8429-322c39fe7110&tab=digestviewer) y [Link-2](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Adding-grand-total-to-column-chart/m-p/424691)

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso En el [Link-1](https://www.pbiusergroup.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=486310e3-bb0c-4871-8da9-c7d6fb0545ed&CommunityKey=b35c8468-2fd8-4e1a-8429-322c39fe7110&tab=digestviewer) no busco mostrar el total de todas la barras al final del grafico, lo que quiero es mostrar el Total de la [tabla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VuYC.png) que agregue al inicio de mi pregunta

Comment: @Jhon Doe esta dificil... preguntaste en la comunidad de Power BI??

Comment: por que no conviertes la duracion a minutos y usas minutos para calcular el total??? al ser valor dumerico si te permitira usarlo ese valor lo farmeteas entonces a tiempo ...