# Como cargar segmentación de datos por defecto

Tags: date, powerbi

Estoy en la realización de un reporte en Power BI, en el cual tengo un filtro por mes, lo que busco es que al momento de abrir el reporte me cargue por defecto el mes actual, en este caso seria el mes de septiembre. La siguiente es la grafica que he creado de segmentación de datos o mas conocida como filtro por cada mes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existirá alguna manera de obtener el mes actual y que al momento de cargar el reporte se cargue con dicho valor en el filtro. Espero que alguien me pueda dar un poco de orientación en como realizarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Tal cual lo planteas no es posible. Puedes solucionarlo mediante otros artilugios, aunque no sean muy elegantes.

Una solución pasa por tener un filtro adicional con por ejemplo dos valores: Mes actual, Mes anterior.

Para hacerlo debes crear una columna:

```
Mes relativo = 
VAR Meses de diferencia = ((12 * YEAR([Fecha])) + MONTH([Fecha])) - ((12 * YEAR(max(Venta[Fecha])) + MONTH(max(Venta[Fecha]))))

RETURN
IF([Meses de diferencia]=0
; "Mes actual"
; "Mes anterior")
```

Y con ella montar un filtro
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque, hay diferentes factores que pueden hacer variar esta estrategia, dependiendo del modelo de datos. En este ejemplo se muestra con el mes-año, y no con solo el mes como tu muestras.

En [este enlace](http://blog.blauservices.com/?p=1895) tienes la descripción de esta solución.

Comment: Seguiré el enlace cualquier duda aquí te comento, adicional he planteado otra pregunta [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/483980/como-mostrar-el-total-de-tabla-en-grafico-de-columnas-agrupadas), crees que puedas darme una orientación en como conseguirlo ?